# Is there a MS API for writing media containers?

Tags: winapi, video, directshow, mp4, ms-media-foundation

Does Microsoft have a good API for writing media containers (mp4, avi ...)? I have a H.264 video stream and also some timestamps that I want to be able to write to a file. I found this overview of media APIs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but it's difficult to extract just what I need ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [AVIFile API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756805%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) exists in all versions of Windows but can only create AVI files. They can contain any data format
2. [DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - writes AVI, writes MP4 (as well as MKV, MOV etc) through third party components (worth mentioning: http://gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4), no support in Windows RT due to legacy status of the API
3. [Media Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - "successor" to DirectShow, limited availability in Windows versions before Windows 7

All have open source wrappers for .NET

Media Foundation [MPEG-4 File Sink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757763%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in particular:

> The MPEG-4 file sink creates MP4 files. For more information about the MP4 file format, refer to the following standards documents:

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is the answer I was looking for, even though the microsoft documentation is just complete gibberish.

Comment: @Deanna: No problem, I did not mention it because it's really outdated for now. Worst container among mentioned, AVI constraints were fine earlier and easily hit nowadays. Actually I would not recommend it at all. MP4 is no much better, except perhaps patent story, however there are others as well.

Comment: Just a note: there's an open source MP4 mux for DirectShow here: gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4

Comment: "is no much better" above is a typo, and it is supposed to be "is so much better".